# No module named trainer

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a very simple trainer that follows the sample directory structure:

```
/dist
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  /trainer
    __init__.py
    task.py
```

Under the /dist directory, runs fine locally:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine local train 
    --package-path=trainer
    --module-name=trainer.task
```

Now, when trying to deploy it, under the /dist directory and this command:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training testA
    --package-path=trainer
    --module-name=trainer.task
    --staging-bucket=$JOB_DIR
    --region us-central1
```

It gives me an error "No moduled name trainer"

```
INFO    2017-04-13 12:28:35 -0700   master-replica-0        Installing collected packages: pyyaml, scipy, scikit-learn, trainer
INFO    2017-04-13 12:28:38 -0700   master-replica-0        Successfully installed pyyaml-3.12 scikit-learn-0.18.1 scipy-0.18.1 trainer-0.1
INFO    2017-04-13 12:28:38 -0700   master-replica-0        Running command: python -m trainer.task
ERROR   2017-04-13 12:28:38 -0700   master-replica-0        /usr/bin/python: No module named trainer
```

EDIT:
here is the content of setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'pyyaml',
    'scipy==0.18.1',
    'scikit-learn'
]
setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    description='Classifier test'
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing an important line in your setup.py, the `packages` argument to the `setup` function invocation (cf [these instructions](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#basic-use)). Try this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['pyyaml','scipy==0.18.1','scikit-learn']
setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='Classifier test'
)
```

I've updated the CloudML Engine [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#to_include_additional_pypi_dependencies) (may take a few days to propagate).

I replicated your command using `--package-path=trainer` and the above changes, and things run properly in the cloud.

Finally, although it is harmless, the `__init__.py` in `dist/` is unnecessary and can safely be removed.

Comment: Thank you, works fine now. And cool that you updated the docs.